# Realm List not saving data

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am fetching data from FireBase and save it inside my realm but it is not working as expected :

```
for doc in docs {
    let shopData = doc.data()
    let newShop = RLMShop()
    newShop.shopName = shopData["name"] as? String ?? "Empty Name"
    self.saveShop(shop: newShop) // My issue is here 
}
```

My saveShop function :

```
    func saveShop(shop: RLMShop) {
       do {
          try realm.write {
            realm.add(shop)
          }
       } catch {
        print("Error saving shop \(error)")
    }
}
```

Calling save function is not saving my object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are creating a `RLMShop` object but it is not linked to a `RLMShopsCategory` object, therefore your `shopsList` will not contain the new object.

```
// Fetch the RLMShopsCategory that you wish to add the RLMShop too
// Using Primary Key here just as an example
let shopsCategory = realm.object(ofType: RLMShopsCategory.self, forPrimaryKey: "YourKey")

for doc in docs {
    let shopData = doc.data()
    let newShop = RLMShop()
    newShop.shopName = // setting the properties etc

    // This is the part you are missing
    // You need to append the newShop to your shopsCategory object
    try! realm.write {
       shopsCategory.shopsList.append(newShop)
    }
}
```